# Spark 2.0 Standalone mode Dynamic Resource Allocation Worker Launch Error

Tags: apache-spark, jupyter-notebook, apache-spark-2.0

I'm running Spark 2.0 on Standalone mode, successfully configured it to launch on a server and also was able to configure Ipython Kernel PySpark as option into Jupyter Notebook. Everything works fine but I'm facing the problem that for each Notebook that I launch, all of my 4 workers are assigned to that application. So if another person from my team try to launch another Notebook with PySpark kernel, it simply does not work until I stop the first notebook and release all the workers.

To solve this problem I'm trying to follow the instructions from [Spark 2.0 Documentation](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/job-scheduling.html#dynamic-resource-allocation).
So, on my `$SPARK_HOME/conf/spark-defaults.conf` I have the following lines:

```
spark.dynamicAllocation.enabled    true
spark.shuffle.service.enabled      true
spark.dynamicAllocation.executorIdleTimeout    10
```

Also, on `$SPARK_HOME/conf/spark-env.sh` I have:

```
export SPARK_WORKER_MEMORY=1g
export SPARK_EXECUTOR_MEMORY=512m
export SPARK_WORKER_INSTANCES=4
export SPARK_WORKER_CORES=1
```

But when I try to launch the workers, using `$SPARK_HOME/sbin/start-slaves.sh`, only the first worker is successfully launched. The log from the first worker end up like this:

> 16/11/24 13:32:06 INFO Worker: Successfully registered with master
>   spark://cerberus:7077

But the log from workers 2-4 show me this error:

> INFO ExternalShuffleService: Starting shuffle service on port 7337
>   with useSasl = false 16/11/24 13:32:08 ERROR Inbox: Ignoring error
>   java.net.BindException: Address already in use

It seems (to me) that the first worker successfully starts the shuffle-service at port 7337, but the workers 2-4 "does not know" about this and try to launch another shuffle-service on the same port.

The problem occurs also for all workers (1-4) if I first launch a shuffle-service (using `$SPARK_HOME/sbin/start-shuffle-service.sh`) and then try to launch all the workers (`$SPARK_HOME/sbin/start-slaves.sh`).

Is any option to get around this? To be able to all workers verfy if there is a shuffle service running and connect to it instead of try to create a new service?

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue and seemed to get it working by removing the spark.shuffle.service.enabled item from the config file (in fact I don't have any dynamicAllocation-related items in there) and instead put this in the SparkConf when I request a SparkContext:

```
sconf = pyspark.SparkConf() \
    .setAppName("sc1") \
    .set("spark.dynamicAllocation.enabled", "true") \
    .set("spark.shuffle.service.enabled", "true")
sc1 = pyspark.SparkContext(conf=sconf)
```

I start the master & slaves as normal:

```
$SPARK_HOME/sbin/start-all.sh
```

And I have to start one instance of the shuffler-service:

```
$SPARK_HOME/sbin/start-shuffle-service.sh
```

Then I started two notebooks with this context and got them both to do a small job. The first notebook's application does the job and is in the RUNNING state, the second notebook's application is in the WAITING state. After a minute (default idle timeout), the resources get reallocated and the second context gets to do its job (and both are in RUNNING state).

Hope this helps,
John